# iTextSharp 4.1.6 display Image from Byte[]

Tags: c#, itext

I am currently developing a web application where i have to generate a PDF with an image in it. I have to use iTextSharp 4.1.6 because it is the last LGPL version. The previous version of our app used v5.5.11.

The image is dynamically created at runtime as byte[]. This would work fine in iTextSharp 5.5.11. However, with 4.1.6 it doesn't display the image in the PDF file.

When i use a hardcoded path as image source instead of the byte[], it displays the image just like i want.

```
//This works
Image qrCode = Image.GetInstance(@"C:\Users\Me\Pictures\asdf.jpg");
//This doesn´t
Image qrCode = Image.GetInstance(QRGenerator.GenerateQRCode(ticketUrl));
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please read [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) Then read [What happens if stolen software is published as Open Source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/435/what-happens-if-stolen-software-is-published-as-open-source/437#437) Your conclusion should be that you can't use iTextSharp 4.1.6, and that, if you do, you are on your own. Also: why do you think that functionality available in a version dating from 2017 would also be present in a version dating from 2009?

Comment: From here I can tell the difference between a string and an array of bytes. Maybe write your bytes to a file first, then your before/after will be identical, and you'll be tackling a new problem :)

Comment: @Davesoft I forgot to mention that Image.GetInstance() has several overloads which can take different parameters like a file path (string), streams, bytearrays...

However, this isn´t relevant anymore. We mistakenly thought that iTextSharp 4.1.6 would be free to use commercially in out application, which isn´t the case. See @BrunoLowagie´s comment.

Comment: @croth Any LGPL licensed software is free to be used in commercial software if you obey the license (make the source available etc.) This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705697/itext-2-1-7-in-commercial-project. Update: I just saw that BL got the answer deleted.